# What does this BSOD error message mean?

Tags: bsod

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    3081

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   be
  BCP1: 00000000001A4825
  BCP2: FD700001C61A0025
  BCP3: FFFFF880009A9940
  BCP4: 000000000000000A
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  768_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\072315-37611-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Oli\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-73960-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: What is the stop code? Without it, its going to be really hard to tell you what this message is for. If you don't know, you can open the 072315-37611-01.dmp file with a memory dump viewer to retreive it. nirsoft offers such tool.

Comment: Try updating your nVidia drivers.  If you've overclocked your graphics card, it may be having problems as a result.  Check the fans on your system and graphics card.  You should also open your system and blow out any dust that might cause high temperatures.

Comment: upload the file C:\Windows\Minidump\072315-37611-01.dmp so that we can debug it.

Answer (score 3):

with the available information I'd wager it's

BCCode: BE   0x000000BE

Bug Check 0xBE: ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY

a stop code would be very useful (to verify, the BCC said BE which would typically be 0x000000BE for stop code), or the memory dump file (you can upload it to dropbox or skydrive, I'd recommend just using a bsod dump viewer and dropping the output to dropbox though, it'd make troubleshooting it faster).
Link in case more up to date information is available:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560161.aspx

The document describes what parameters are shown on the BSOD screen (should be in the dump as well)
1: the address that was attempted to write to
2: PTE contents
3: reserved
4: reserved

the following excerpt is also on the page:

"If the driver responsible for the error can be identified, its name is printed on the blue screen and stored in memory at the location (PUNICODE_STRING) KiBugCheckDriver."

I suggest you analyze the BSOD crash dump to find which driver tried to write to read only memory and either update or remove it if applicable, if not either option is available I would suggest talking to the hardware manufacturer of the relevant device, it could either be malfunctioning or the driver could have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by the following file: `nvlddmkm.sys`

```
ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY
```

If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen,
restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow
these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer
for any Windows updates you might need.

If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
your computer, press <kbd>F8</kbd> to select **Advanced Startup Options**, and then
select **Safe Mode**.

### Technical Information:

```
*** STOP: 0x000000be (0x00000000001a4825, 0xfd700001c61a0025, 0xfffff880009a9940, 0x000000000000000a)

*** nvlddmkm.sys - Address 0xfffff8800590ce29 base at 0xfffff88005897000 DateStamp 0x5581075a
```